# OAuth2-Autoconfigure: There is no client authentication. Try adding an appropriate authentication filter

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I know there are similar questions on stackoverflow but none of them helped me. I added `web.ignoring` for `/oauth/**` as suggested but it still doesn't work.

When I try to access: `/oauth/token?grant_type=password&password=123456&username=admin` (of course I add Basic auth with the appropriate client id and secret key), I'm receiving the following error message:

```
{
    "error": "unauthorized",
    "error_description": "There is no client authentication. Try adding an appropriate authentication filter."
}
```

What could possibly be broken now?

I'm kinda disappointed in how easily spring boot's oauth breaks. It's like lottery, you turn off your PC and on the next day something breaks from nowhere (without code changes). Are there better ways to do that?

I put a breakpoint at TokenEndPoint.postAccessToken and Principal seems to be null.

Since it can be anything being broken, I uploaded the project on GitHub: https://github.com/Warrolen/stackoverflow-question/tree/master/forum

[image]

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/topics/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/users/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/webjars/**", "/oauth/**");
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
                .inMemory()
                .withClient("trusted")
                .secret(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode("secret"))
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token")
                .autoApprove(true)
                .scopes("read", "write")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(15 * 60)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(30 * 60);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints
                .tokenStore(tokenStore)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

}
```

Comment: It seems to be bubolechka

Comment: Added GitHub link: https://github.com/Warrolen/stackoverflow-question/tree/master/forum